# Windows Phone 8.1 ListView ItemTemplate Grid Holding event not firing on device

Tags: listview, grid, windows-phone-8.1, datatemplate

I have a bound ListView which uses a Grid as an ItemTemplate. The grid has a MenuFlyout which is triggered by the Holding event. In the emulator, all is well, but running on a device (a Lumia 635 with Windows 8.1 Update), the Grid Holding event doesn't fire.

If I add a holding event to the ListView, this event will fire, but then I have no reference to the item being held down.

To replicate, 1) add this inside the MainPage tags of the default page

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock"  x:Key="GridText">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10" x:Name="scrollRecord" Background="DarkMagenta">
        <TextBlock x:Name="textRecord" FontSize="18" />
    </ScrollViewer>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10">
        <ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Holding="Grid_Holding">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                            <MenuFlyout>
                                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="buttonTick"
                                                        Text="Add"
                                                        Click="buttonAdd_Click"/>
                                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="buttonUntick"
                                                        Text="Remove"
                                                        Click="buttonRemove_Click"/>
                            </MenuFlyout>
                        </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>

                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource GridText}"  Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Colour}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

2. Create a class named Route, and paste this in

   [DataContract]
   class Route : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   ```
   public Route()
   {
   }

   public Route(string colour)
   {
       Colour = colour;
   }

   [DataMember]
   public string Colour { get; set; }

   protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
       if (handler != null)
           handler(this, e);
   }

   protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
   {
       OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
   ```

   }

   class RouteList : ObservableCollection //ElementCollection 
   {

   }
3. In MainPage.xaml.cs, select everything beneath the class definition and it's opening curly bracket and paste this in

   public MainPage()
       {
           this.InitializeComponent();
           this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
           this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
       }

   ```
   RouteList routes;

   void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       routes = new RouteList();
       routes.Add(new Route("Red"));
       routes.Add(new Route("Orange"));
       routes.Add(new Route("Pink"));
       routes.Add(new Route("Blue"));
       routes.Add(new Route("Violet"));

       listView.ItemsSource = routes;

       //DataTemplate t = listView.ItemTemplate;
       //AddText("gridLayout holding)
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
   /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
   protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
   {
       // TODO: Prepare page for display here.

       // TODO: If your application contains multiple pages, ensure that you are
       // handling the hardware Back button by registering for the
       // Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed event.
       // If you are using the NavigationHelper provided by some templates,
       // this event is handled for you.
   }



   private void Grid_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       try
       {
           AddText("Grid_Holding fired " + e.HoldingState.ToString());
           //ShowFlyout(sender);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           AddText(ex.Message);
       }
   }

   private void ShowFlyout(object sender)
   {
       FrameworkElement senderElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
       FlyoutBase flyoutBase = FlyoutBase.GetAttachedFlyout(senderElement);
       flyoutBase.ShowAt(senderElement);
   }

   private void AddText(string s)
   {
       textRecord.Text += s + "\n";
       //scrollRecord.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollRecord.ScrollableHeight);
       scrollRecord.ChangeView(0, scrollRecord.ScrollableHeight,1.0f,false);
   }

   private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       try
       {
           AddText("Adding...");
           MenuFlyoutItem m = sender as MenuFlyoutItem;
           Route route = m.DataContext as Route;
           if (route != null)
           {
               string colour = route.Colour + "+";
               routes.Add(new Route(colour));
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           AddText(ex.Message);

       }
       AddText("Finished");
   }

   private void buttonRemove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       MenuFlyoutItem m = sender as MenuFlyoutItem;
       Route route = m.DataContext as Route;
       if (route != null)
       {
           routes.Remove(route);
       }
   }

   private void listView_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       try
       {

           AddText("listView_Holding fired " + e.HoldingState.ToString());
           //ShowFlyout(sender);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           AddText(ex.Message);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: After all this effort, I rebooted my phone, and now it's working OK.

Comment: It worked a bit for a while. The capture of the Holding event seems rather intermittent on my phone, whereas the emulator works every time. Capturing the holding event of the listview works just fine, so I may use that instead, but the grid's holding event would be more useful

Comment: Well, I am dozy! It turns out when using the emulator, I am always clicking on the text in the grid. When I use my finger, I am often not directly over the text, so the grid holding doesn't get fired. The following xaml shows this up.

Comment: <Border Background="DarkOrange" Holding="Border_Holding" Tapped="Border_Tapped" Height="50" Width="300">
                        <!--Grid x:Name="gridLayout"  Width="{Binding ElementName=listView, Path=ActualWidth}"  Holding="Grid_Holding" -->
                            <Grid x:Name="gridLayout" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Holding="Grid_Holding" IsHoldingEnabled="True">

Comment: One fix is to add a background="Red" to the grid. Transparent backgrounds do not capture events. I think I remember this from before - maybe silverlight's canvas.